# CUDA out of memory and BERT

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Is there a way that I can manage how much memory to reserve for Pytorch? I've trying to finetune a BERT model from Huggingface and I'm already using a A100 Nvidia GPU with 80GiB of GPU from Paperspace and still managed to go "CUDA out of memory". I'm not training from scratch or anything and my dataset is composed by less than 250,000 datum. I don't know if I'm missing something or if there is a way to reduce the allocated memory for Pytorch.

(Seriously, I just wanna cry now.)

[Error specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0zNg.png)

I've tried reducing my batch size at training dataset and eval dataset, also turning fp16=Tue. I even tried with the gradient accumulation but nothing seems to work. I've been cleaning with gc.collect() and torch.cuda.empty_cache() and restarting my kernel machine. I even tried with a smaller model.

Comment: Please share your training, batch loading and model creation code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.